# Who executes faster - for or while loop

Tags: c++

So basically I would like to know, who is faster from these loops in C++ language?
Basically, which of these examples would compile faster -

```
int S = 1, D = 2, d = 1;
for(int x = 0; x < 10000; x++) {
  S += D/2-d *s;
}
```

and

```
int S = 1, D = 2, d = 1, x = 0;
while(x < 10000) {
  x++;
  S += D/2-d * S;
}
```

Comment: (1) "would compile faster"? do you mean "run faster?" (2) Let the compiler do the micro optimizations, you should do what is more readable. readability is for programmers and optimizations are for compilers

Comment: possible duplicate of [What loop is faster, while or for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629174/what-loop-is-faster-while-or-for)

Comment: Does it really matter with the overhead of the loop? If it really does then a lot more must be provided. Which architecture are you running on, which compiler and which optimizations settings for the compiler? In theory the for loop could be removed altogether and the while could be replaced by x = 10000;

Comment: Well, basicaly, I men't run faster :), sorry about that.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Blimey.. my comment was only there for a handful of seconds!

Answer (score 11):

The second example would probably compile slightly faster because it is 76 characters long, as opposed to the first's 77 characters, and it uses less complicated language constructs (by less complicated, I mean less complicated to parse).

Comment: Though I appritiate the fact that you are the only one to address the question "Which will *compile* faster?" I doubt the [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) is the bottle neck of the compiler generating the machine code...

Comment: @amit that has already been addressed in other answers: the code will likely be precisely the same (though only the compiler truly knows and we can only make educated guesses)

Comment: Kind of an absurd answer isn't it? Thecostof compilation is probably more influenced by the different code paths in the compiler than by a single extra character to parse.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas absurd questions merit absurd answers

Comment: Answer was better before attempts were made to make it look sensible

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Initiate humour-recognition program `alpha 4-5-1`. Please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just couldn't bring myself to leave it at one sentence.

Comment: @Seth: Sometimes it's all in the brevity, my friend

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit very true (don't forget, this is a community site, feel free to edit `:)`)

Answer (score 9):

With any half-decent compiler it should compile to **exactly** the same code. In fact, this:

```
for (begin; cond; loop) {
    block;
}
```

Is semantically equivalent to (barring `continue` with the `loop`, as Seth Carnegie suggested below):

```
{
    begin;

    while (cond) {
         block;
         loop;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might not be **exactly** the same code, the `x++` in the for loop will be after changing `S`, won't it?

Comment: @amit: Since `x++` is not used in the expression `S += D/2-d * S` and neither has side-effects the two expressions may be switched arbitrarily by the compiler. So neither order is defined :)

Comment: Those two are not exactly equivalent (things with `continue` and a few other things)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: even then they are equivalent.

Comment: @nightcracker no, because if you `continue` in your `while` loop, the `loop` expression will not be run

Comment: I think you mean "semantically equivalent". They're obvisouly not syntactically equivalent because they use different syntax.

Comment: Additionally, the `while` example introduces two scopes whereas the `for` only introduces one

Comment: Seth Carnegie: Not really, if you use C99: `for (int i=0; ...`.

Comment: What I mean is that you can't use variables from `block` in `loop`, like you could in the `while` example. But the answer is pretty correct so +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between compile time and execution time. For execution time, compilers nowadays will most likely generate the same code. Compilation time... most likely the same also.

**Note that your example is incorrect**. The two loops are not equivalent. The increment is executed first in the `while` loop. The equivalent of the `for` loop would be:

```
while(x < 10000) {
  S += D/2-d * S;
  x++;
}
```

Comment: They are completely equivalent, unless the value of `x` has some magical bearing on `S` that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh, you were saying that in this case, it doesn't matter. Couldn't tell from the sarcasm, but yes, you're right.

Comment: There was no sarcasm in my comment at all. The program's meaning is not changed by moving the statement `x++`, so both program variants are equivalent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know, but - "unless the value of x has some magical bearing on S that I'm not aware of?"

Comment: That's not sarcasm. It _is_ somewhat flippant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit being saucy, are we? (yes, I did look up the definition of flippant) :)

Answer (score 0):

The only 'person' able to answer that is a profiler.

On a more theoretical level, a compiler would take them down to the same low level constructs, if fact some compilers turn `for` loops into `while` loops before the generation of IR.

Comment: And it may even unroll the loops if it feels necessary!

Comment: Or since the loop is determinate, it could just calculate the result and just initialise the variables to the values they would be at the end of the loop and remove the loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer this code gives 4 ms (less than 0.1% ) of difference in average. And it doesn't matter which function goes first, a() or b(), the first is slower, so the reason is how scheduler works, I think.

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <QTime>

const long cycles = 1000000000;

void a()    {
    long s = 0;
    for(long x = 0; x < cycles; x++) {
        s++;
    }
}

void b()   {
    long x = 0;
    long s= 0;
    while(x < cycles) {
        x++;
        s++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
    QTime t1;
    t1.start();

    b();

    int i1 = t1.elapsed();
    t1.restart();

    a();

    int i2 = t1.elapsed();

    std::cout << i1 <<"\n"<< i2 <<"\n---\n";
    return 0;
}
```