# While loop is more efficient than for loop. What could be the reason?

Tags: c++, loops

I was doing a LeetCode challenge ([here](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-ii-input-array-is-sorted/#/description)) for fun and was surprised that the while loop was more efficient than the for loop. I would have expected the compiler to generate identical code (also as per these [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34711087/1566187)), but the run times are different.

The while loop was around 3 ms, whilst the for loop took around 6ms. I repeated a couple of times and it seemd to be often like that.

I don't have the test cases unfortunately, and I don't have any information about compiler used, the architecture or optimizations set. I think it is not important because the programs are almost identical and use the same compiler, architecture and options surely.

Any ideas or experiences in that matter ?

For loop:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& numbers, int target) {
    int upper = numbers.size() - 1;
    int lower = 0;
    int sum;

    for (;lower<upper;) {
        sum = numbers[lower] + numbers[upper];
        if (sum == target) {
            return vector<int> { lower+1, upper+1 };
        } else if (sum > target) {
            upper--;
        } else {
            lower++;
        }
    }
}
```

While loop:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& numbers, int target) {
    int upper = numbers.size() - 1;
    int lower = 0;
    int sum;

    while (lower<upper) {
        sum = numbers[lower] + numbers[upper];
        if (sum == target) {
            return vector<int> { lower+1, upper+1 };
        } else if (sum > target) {
            upper--;
        } else {
            lower++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: Strange; can't think of a reason for it to do that unless the code generation is really poor and optimisations are turned off

Comment: How many times did you run the loops?  Were optimizations on?  Micro-benchmarking can be very tricky.

Comment: GCC generates [nearly identical assembly for both](https://godbolt.org/g/J7sh0n). Only difference I can see is that some instructions are in different order.

Comment: *because the programs are almost identical and use the same compiler, architecture and options surely*  -- Unless you run the site, you don't know what the options are, so no assumptions can be made.

Comment: @user2079303 - it is a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Just copy and paste the code into the corresponding text area on the linked page.

Comment: @user2079303 the assembly codes for the two loops are identical, see my answer.

Comment: @user2079303 I tend to believe you. Yes, how come the difference in run time ? The while loop constantly performs better than the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You did not run enough or long enough tests, benchmarks in milliseconds is hard to verify.

A better way is to compare the generated assembly: [for-loop](https://godbolt.org/g/WVIT01) and [while-loop](https://godbolt.org/g/6wPyt0).
The snippets are compiled with maximum optimization (`-O3`), using g++ 6.3.
From this it is clear that there is no performance difference at all, since the assembly for the two is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

All loops follow the same template:

```
{
// Initialize
LOOP: 
if(!(/* Condition */) ) {
    goto END
}

// Loop body

// Loop increment/decrement
goto LOOP
}
END:
```

Your test must have differed by the available processing power on your CPU.

Comment: I would avoid the negation in the condition, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: If the negation wasn't there, then your c++ coded condition would be opposite of what it is supposed to be. This is under-the-hood of c++

Comment: That's not what I meant. I would change the if statement to just check condition and then let the if body contain the loop body, increment step, and go-to loop.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. I don't make the rules