# filtering 2d arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array where I need to filter the rows having date field (3d column)

```
var data = [
['1','a','12-12-2019','A'],
['2','b','','A'],
['3','c','12-1-2019','A'],
['4','d','','A'],
];
```

The expected result is

```
result = [
['1','a','12-12-2019','A'],
['3','c','12-1-2019','A'],
];
```

Using for loop for comprisons is time intensive, Is there a fastest way to retrieve?

Comment: a for loop ...?

Comment: Not by using traditional for loop.

Comment: I have 3000 rows to filter

Comment: for loop will be fastest when it comes to speed, and you should also add on what basis you're filtering data ?

Comment: do you mean for each or this one for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){  } ?

Comment: The basis is existance of date field, as already mentioned in question 3rd column

Comment: No way to prevent using loops and 3000 rows is not a lot

Comment: @CodeGuy will that be always at same index ?

Comment: Yes that will be always at same index

Comment: @CodeGuy added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666633/9624435) with simple for loop you can check

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't worry about using a loop to do that - this is what loops are for.

You could just use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to make sure that there's a value in the 2nd position of each array, returning whether it's truthy or not.

```
var data = [
  ['1','a','12-12-2019','A'],
  ['2','b','','A'],
  ['3','c','12-1-2019','A'],
  ['4','d','','A'],
];

// You're using a Google Apps script, so this is ES5
const result = data.filter(function(item) {
  return item[2];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems pretty straightforward to just use Array.filter, checking to see if the date field is empty or not.

```js
var data = [
['1','a','12-12-2019','A'],
['2','b','','A'],
['3','c','12-1-2019','A'],
['4','d','','A'],
];

var filtered = data.filter(e => e[2]);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
var data = [
  ['1', 'a', '12-12-2019', 'A'],
  ['2', 'b', '', 'A'],
  ['3', 'c', '12-1-2019', 'A'],
  ['4', 'd', '', 'A'],
];

// check any of the string matched date pattern
let res = data.filter(arr => arr.some(str => /^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/.test(str)))

console.log(res)
```

For the older browser, you can just do it with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
var data = [
  ['1', 'a', '12-12-2019', 'A'],
  ['2', 'b', '', 'A'],
  ['3', 'c', '12-1-2019', 'A'],
  ['4', 'd', '', 'A'],
];


var res = data.filter(function(arr) {
  // check length of date formated elements
  return arr.filter(function(str) {
    return /^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/.test(str)
  }).length;
});

console.log(res)
```

---

If you just want to check the 3rd element always then there isn't any need of the nested loop.

```js
var data = [
  ['1', 'a', '12-12-2019', 'A'],
  ['2', 'b', '', 'A'],
  ['3', 'c', '12-1-2019', 'A'],
  ['4', 'd', '', 'A'],
];


var res = data.filter(function(arr) {
  // check 3rd value is correct date value
  return /^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/.test(arr[0])
  // if value would be empty all other case then simply 
  // return the value since empty values are falsy
  // return arr[2];
});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I am actually using this for an Google apps script, so I cant use => operator

Comment: Also some methods are not supported

Comment: @CodeGuy, all of that should be mentioned in your question. We should not have to read those requirements in comments.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to speed `for` loop is fastest as your value to match is always at fixed index so you can just directly check and value and push your data

```js
var data = [['1','a','12-12-2019','A'],['2','b','','A'],['3','c','12-1-2019','A'],['4','d','','A'],];

let op = []

for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  if(!data[i][2]){
    op.push(data[i])
  }
}

console.log(op)
```

Comment: You certain a `while` loop isn't fastest?

Comment: or array.filter?

Comment: @charlietfl well that depends implementations and i have seen some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629174/which-loop-is-faster-while-or-for) in most of answers it says so,

Comment: Just throwing it out there. Hard to know without a perf test.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
['1','a','12-12-2019','A'],
['2','b','','A'],
['3','c','12-1-2019','A'],
['4','d','','A'],
];

d = data.filter(i => i[2].match(/\d\d?\-\d\d?\-\d{4}/))
console.log(d)
```

If you really care the time, then use c++, c, rust or anything, btw, JS is the fastest interpreted language.